Is that an optimal solution for this instance of MS-RCPSP (Multi-Skilled Resource-Constrained Project Scheduling Problem)
I'm questioning whether this is the optimal solution for this instance of the MS-RCPSP (Multi-Skilled Resource-Constrained Project Scheduling Problem). I have checked the assignment and would like to discuss the current Cmax, which is 11. Is it possible to achieve a result lower than this ?






Assuming that all skills required by a task need to be provided simultaneously, I have a MIP model that confirms the earliest completion time is 11 (albeit with a different solution).

thank you so much !!
